# Adding a Weight to Letter grades and Calculating how many individual letter grades there are

Tags: microsoft-excel

[image: GPA 100 pt scale conversion]

I work at a university and I recently created a spreadsheet that converts percentage grades to their equivalent letter grade and then I assign a Credit to each grade which is a method of weighting the grade.

The table (Column A - Column C) represents one individual student's high school transcript. In other words all their marks from grade 9 - grade 12.

1. Column A is the percentage grade from every course
2. Column B is that percentage grade converted to a letter grade;
3. Column C (Credit) is a weighting I give the particular result (e.g. 1 or 0.5);

The "Credit" value is a method I use to assign more (or less) weight to certain marks over others even though the letter grade may be identical.

The next step that I would love to automate is totaling the "Credit" column by letter grade. In `F2:F13` I have a list of all possible letter grades.  I would like `G2:G13` to list the total credits (column C) for each of those letter grades.

For example if I had the following data

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **NUMBER** | **LETTER** | **CREDIT** |
| 96 | A | 1 |
| 95 | A | 1 |
| 90 | A- | 1 |
| 81 | B- | 0.5 |
| 95 | A | 0.5 |

Then my totals would be

| F | G |
| --- | --- |
| **Grades** | **Total Credit** |
| A | 2.5 |
| A- | 1 |
| B+ | 0 |
| B | 0 |
| B- | 0.5 |

Comment: @ScottCraner I have included a image of what I have currently drawn up in Excel. I hope this helps visualize what I am saying more.

Comment: @BlindSpots Column A Number is the gpa of a course in number form which is then converted into Column B to represent the letter grade that the first number would equal in an A-F format. The Last Column C is how much credit that course is worth. Let me know if that clears it up. I manually enter in column C using a transcript that shows the value of the course.

Comment: @BlindSpots I started commenting a realized it was going to be too complicated so I included a new example in my original post. I hope that helps clear it up.

Comment: I don't think the formula below is the one I want for this. I want to count how many of each individual letter I have.

Comment: Yes that is perfect! Thank you for giving me those two formulas! You have been so helpful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Formula in G2 if Counting by Credits

```
=SUMIF(B:B,F2,C:C)

# If you have Office 365 you can use the following 
# formula in G2 rather than copying the previous one down

=SUMIF(B:B,F2:F13,C:C)
```

### Formula in G2 if ignoring credits

```
=COUNTIF(B:B,F2)

# If you have Office 365 you can use the following 
# formula in G2 rather than copying the previous one down

=COUNTIF(B:B,F2:F13)
```

<sup>***** *Credit to [Scott Craner](https://superuser.com/users/567231/scott-craner) for noting the single formula approach.*</sup>

##### SUMIF Function

You use the [SUMIF](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sumif-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b) function to sum the values in a range that meet criteria that you specify.

**Syntax:** `SUMIF(range, criteria, [sum_range])`

##### COUNTIF function

Use [COUNTIF](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/countif-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34), one of the statistical functions, to count the number of cells that meet a criterion

**Syntax:** `COUNTIF(range, criteria)`

---

## Extra

Instead of nested IF functions to calculate the letter grade, you could use a IFS function or a lookup table with XMATCH

##### IFS instead of nested IF

```
=IFS(A2>92,"A",  A2>89,"A-",
     A2>86,"B+", A2>83,"B", A2>79,"B-",
     A2>76,"C+", A2>72,"C", A2>69,"C-",
     A2>66,"D+", A2>62,"D", A2>59,"D-",
     TRUE,"F" )
```

[image]

##### XMATCH instead of IF/IFS

```
=INDEX(grade, XMATCH(D2,pct,-1))

# Named Ranges
# grade=A2:A13  pct=B2:B13
```

[image]